# Show that $(X,\tau)$ is Locally Compact and Locally Path Connected but not Compact

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let $X=\mathbb{N}$ and equip $X$ with the topology
$\tau=\{U \subset X: (2n-1) \in U \implies 2n \in U\}$

(a) Prove that $(X,\tau)$ is locally compact but not compact

(b) Determine the connected components of $(X,\tau)$ and show that $(X,\tau)$ is locally path connected.

For (a), $$\mathbb{N}=\cup_{i=1,3,5,\ldots}\{i,i+1\}$$
Each of $\{i,i+1\}$ is open and this cover doesn't admit a finite subcover. Hence $(X,\tau)$ is not compact. Moreover each such $\{i,i+1\}$ is closed. The set of limit point for each such is $\phi$. Thus for each $n \in X$, if $n$ were odd, then $n \in \{n, n+1\}$ and $n \in \{n-1,n\}$ if $n$ were even and each such set is compact.

(b) The connected components of $(X,\tau)$ are $\{i,i+1\}$ for each $i$ odd. These are the only connected components. But I am unable to show that each such set is path connected. If I can show this, then I will be done.

How do I show this?
Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take $f: [0,1] \to X$, $f(t) = i$ for $0 \le t < \frac{1}{2}$ and $f(t) = i+1$ for $\frac{1}{2} \le t < 1$. Then the inverse image of any open set is open. The preimage of $i$ is $[0,\frac{1}{2})$, the preimage of $\{i,i+1\}$ is $[0,1]$ and any open set containing just $i$ or $i$ and $i+1$ will have one of the two preceding preimages.